# Running a server for Minetest

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, gaming

I hope this is the correct stackexchange site to ask this question.

I am trying to run a minetest server from my computer (Linux) but I'm unable to connect it from another computer connected to the internet in the different network. I'm running the minetest server using minetestserver and it gives the following output :

```
2016-07-13 20:45:22: WARNING[Main]: Couldn't find a locale directory!
2016-07-13 20:45:22: [Main]: Automatically selecting world at [/root/.minetest/worlds/world]
2016-07-13 20:45:22: WARNING[Main]: NodeDefManager: Ignoring CONTENT_IGNORE redefinition
2016-07-13 20:45:22: ACTION[Main]:         .__               __                   __   
2016-07-13 20:45:22: ACTION[Main]:   _____ |__| ____   _____/  |_  ____   _______/  |_ 
2016-07-13 20:45:22: ACTION[Main]:  /     \|  |/    \_/ __ \   __\/ __ \ /  ___/\   __\
2016-07-13 20:45:22: ACTION[Main]: |  Y Y  \  |   |  \  ___/|  | \  ___/ \___ \  |  |  
2016-07-13 20:45:22: ACTION[Main]: |__|_|  /__|___|  /\___  >__|  \___  >____  > |__|  
2016-07-13 20:45:22: ACTION[Main]:       \/        \/     \/          \/     \/        
2016-07-13 20:45:22: ACTION[Main]: World at [/root/.minetest/worlds/world]
2016-07-13 20:45:22: ACTION[Main]: Server for gameid="minetest" listening on 0.0.0.0:30000.
```

Which indeed is supposed to be the output if everything is successful.

When the server is running,

```
netstat -na | grep 30000
```

gives

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30000           0.0.0.0:*
```

I have also configured my router for port forwarding. I tried to ping my public IP from another machine connected to the internet but it didn't work.

I tried using `netcat` to get some idea but I didn't get much, partly because I didn't really know what to do. Still, I started listening on the 30001 port and sent packets using netcat from the same machine using my local IP in the network (192.168.0.102) and it worked. But when I used my public IP and sent packet from remote machine it doesn't show anything.

When I do traceroute from another machine to my public IP it doesn't really reach my address but ends at some other address; when I do traceroute to google.com or any other website from my server machine, I can see that all requests go through an IP from the same network. I don't really know if that means anything.

I posted this question on [arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1641119) thinking it might be an OS related problem but I wasn't really successful.

**EDIT :**

Output after running `nmap` from remote location :

```
> sudo nmap -sU -sS <public ip> -p 70-80
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-23 13:43 IST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.65 seconds

> sudo nmap -sU -Pn -sS <public ip> -p 70-80
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-23 13:43 IST
Nmap scan report for <public ip>
Host is up (0.12s latency).
PORT   STATE         SERVICE
70/tcp filtered      gopher
71/tcp filtered      netrjs-1
72/tcp filtered      netrjs-2
73/tcp filtered      netrjs-3
74/tcp filtered      netrjs-4
75/tcp filtered      priv-dial
76/tcp filtered      deos
77/tcp filtered      priv-rje
78/tcp filtered      unknown
79/tcp filtered      finger
80/tcp filtered      http
70/udp open|filtered gopher
71/udp open|filtered netrjs-1
72/udp open|filtered netrjs-2
73/udp open|filtered netrjs-3
74/udp open|filtered netrjs-4
75/udp open|filtered priv-dial
76/udp open|filtered deos
77/udp open|filtered priv-rje
78/udp open|filtered vettcp
79/udp open|filtered finger
80/udp open|filtered http
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.15 seconds

sudo nmap -sU -Pn -sS <public ip> -p 29999-30005
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-23 13:50 IST
Nmap scan report for <public ip>
Host is up.
PORT      STATE         SERVICE
29999/tcp filtered      unknown
30000/tcp filtered      unknown
30001/tcp filtered      pago-services1
30002/tcp filtered      unknown
30003/tcp filtered      unknown
30004/tcp filtered      unknown
30005/tcp filtered      unknown
29999/udp open|filtered unknown
30000/udp open|filtered unknown
30001/udp open|filtered unknown
30002/udp open|filtered unknown
30003/udp open|filtered unknown
30004/udp open|filtered unknown
30005/udp open|filtered unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

Minetest [wiki](http://wiki.minetest.com/wiki/Setting_up_a_server) states, that you need to enable forwarding for both UDP and TCP packets. This could be your problem. If it doesn't help do following:

1. First debug the connection from different computer on your local network. Connecting to your local IP from same machine doesn't do the job - this communication is automatically routed through the loopback device and never leaves your machine.
2. Verify your public IP is accessible remotely and does indeed allow connections on port 30000. Many routers drop ICMP (ping) packets from outside networks as a "security" measure to block tracing. Instead try scanning your public IP ports from remote location with tool like nmap. This should also tell you if your ISP blocks connections. Example for port range 70 to 80:

   > nmap -sU -sS 127.0.0.1 -p 70-80

**Side note:**
This was mentioned in the Arch forum already - DON'T run publicly available game server as root. There are too many things that can go wrong. Even if it's just for testing, it's still a very bad idea. Ports with number above 1024 don't need privileged access, you can log in with any normal user account and run the server process. Even for privileged ports you don't need to be root, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l) question.

**Edit:**
Yes - your ip clearly is reachable, but doesn't show it's forwarding the packets to the local network (in that case port 30000 should show OPEN for TCP even if there isn't any device waiting on the local network). It might be blocked by the ISP, it might be caused by the router not doing what it should. I don't think i can help you futher with just this information - you really should test these things:

1. Connect to the minetest server from another machine in local network or simulate this with Virtual Box and bridged adapter.
2. Test that router forwarding works with something easier to verify, for example: TCP port 80 forwarding to apache as suggested by Morn in arch forum.

Comment: I have enabled forwarding for both UDP and TCP packets. I don't have access to another computer on local network so I won't be able to do that. I'll try out the second one though. And thanks for the side note; I'll always be careful in the future.

Comment: I've added the nmap output in the question. It seems like the host is reachable? I'm not sure what else to make of it though.

Comment: Updated the answer, let us know if you'll sort it out.